# How to update child table field from master table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `parent_table` defined as follows:

```
product_id, product_name, product_parent_id
```

and another, `child_table` as below:

```
user_id, product_id
```

Now I have to add `product_parent_id` in child table due to some requirements and need to update existing data with `product_parent_id` so I have added modified `child_table` to have these fields:

```
user_id,product_id, product_parent_id
```

I need an SQL query to update the existing child table with `product_parent_id`.

I have tried this query:

```
UPDATE child_table ct 
   JOIN parent_table pt ON ct.product_id = pt.product_id
   SET ct.parent_product_id = pt.parent_product_id
```

Is this the right solution? I am going to run this on my working project.

Comment: Your SQL is correct

Comment: the way to test it is to first write it as a `select` statement so you can see what is going to happen. Then change it to an `update` statement